# How to Execute the Stored Procedure on Javascript Confirmbutton Click in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, button

I have a .aspx page which has a button "clickme" on which I want to execute a storedprocedure after JavaScript Confirm button is clicked. if user clicks "Yes" then only execute Storedprocedure if "Cancel" pressed do not execute the stored procedure...the button is server control.

Help Appreciated!

Comment: the button is server-side or client-side?

Comment: hello, try this http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx

Comment: i need JavaScript Confirmation code in code behind page...if "yes" pressed execute Storedprocedure if "No" pressed do not execute stored procedure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Page_Load event, put the following code (or you could put the equivalent code in the aspx page).

```
btnSubmitRequest.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return window.confirm('Submit Request?');");
```

Where *btnSubmitRequest* is the ID you gave the button on the aspx page and *Submit Request* is the message you want to display to the user (you must put the message in single quotes). The button must also be created with runat="server" tag.

If the user clicks OK on the JavaScript window, the OnClick event for the button will fire. You can call the stored procedure in there. If the user clicks Cancel on the JavaScript window, the OnClick event will never fire.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the button runat=server you can still catch the click event in javascript and do your javascript.  Simply return true from your javascript if you want it to continue to process the postback normally or false if you want to cancel the postback.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

On JavaScript function click you can do an ajax post to a static web Method and in that method you call perform operations. Check the below link

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Make-AJAX-Call-to-ASP.Net-Server-Side-Web-service-method-using-jQuery.aspx

Note: Use OnClientClick if button is server control..